# Spring actuator healthcheck script for Amazon ECS

Tags: spring, amazon-ecs, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot app which uses spring actuator and under the path: localhost:8080/my-app/health when it's ok it returns:

```
{
"status":"UP"
}
```

when not:

```
{
"status":"DOWN"
}
```

I want ECS to restart the container when the status is down for couple of times. I added the jq to my container definition also I added the healthcheck in the task definition as:

```
...
"healthCheck": {
        "retries": 10,
        "command": [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "[[ $(curl -s 'http://localhost:8080/my-app/health' | jq -r '.status') == \"UP\" ]] && exit 0 || exit 1 "
        ],
        "timeout": 5,
        "interval": 60,
        "startPeriod": 300
      }
...
```

However ECS constantly restarts my service. Can anyone help me and say how create such healthcheck ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to parse the JSON. Just check the HTTP status code.

```
[ "CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:8080/my-app/health || exit 1" ]
```

If the status code is 2xx, the container is ready and healthy.

Comment: Yes that's the best solution, you should always check your http code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that CMD-SHELL run the script using sh which doesn't support `[[...]]` syntax.
Checking container healthcheck logs helped me a lot:

```
docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" <container name> | jq
```